# Force derived class to call base function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, overwrite, base-class

If I derive a class from another one and overwrite a function, I can call the base function by calling `Base::myFunction()` inside the implementation of `myFunc` in the derived class.

However- is there a way to define in my `Base` class that the base function is called in any case, also without having it called explicitly in the overwritten function? (either before or after the derived function executed)

Or even better, if I have a virtual function in my virtual `Base` class, and two implemented private functions `before()` and `after()`, is it possible to define in the `Base` class that before and after the function in any derived class of this `Base` class is called, `before()` and `after()` will be called?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably C++ (`Base::myFunction` seems C++)

Comment: I can't help but think that this calls for aspect oriented programming, although sadly the implementations are still lacking.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
But you can simulate it by calling a different virtual function like so:

```
class Base
{
public:
  void myFunc()
  {
    before();
    doMyFunc();
    after();
  }

  virtual void doMyFunc() = 0;
};
```

Comment: If you make the virtual function protected (or even private) then you disable other code from calling the virtual method directly through a reference to base (not if they have a reference to a derived type, as the derived class can make the method publicly available)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to prevent a derived class from overloading/overriding a method in the base.  You can encourage it by marking methods as 'not overridable' (depending on the language), but there's always a way around it.

In other words, you can't force someone to use your class in a particular way, only tell them the way it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for C++, you cannot have an inherited function "invisibly" called in the way you want.

The only methods that call down through inherited classes are constructors and destructors.